How to remove icons from the MS office title bar?
Excel for Mac 2021 (Version 16.78), and the other office programs in that series, display a lot of "junk" in the title bar. I’d like things cleaned up.
Excess iconography obscures the file name and also makes it very difficult to drag the window to change position.
Is there any way to remove the junk to leave only the window controls and file name?


Note that the space between the three "traffic light" buttons on the left and the AutoSave toggle can always be used to drag the window.

You can customise the "Toolbar". Use either:

From menu bar: Excel > Preferences > Ribbon & Toolbar. Select Quick Access Toolbar tab.
Click on the ellipsis (3 dots in toolbar). Select "More Commands...".

Now you can select items to remove (or to add).

You can't remove the Search box in the toolbar, though mine contracts to a magnifying glass when the window is narrowed.  And this is sooner than in your screenshot - maybe that is version or screen size dependent:

I am using Excel 16.85 (24051214).
Edit:
Even easier for the most common commands. After clicking on the toolbar ellipsis, click on an item in the drop down to remove (or add) it to the toolbar.

Is it possible to remove the "Autosave" toggle?

@hym3242 Yes, in my version of Excel
